# Pointer to read only class

Tags: javascript, security, parse-platform, acl

I have two Classes; Agenda and Events. Multiple events can belong to an Agenda object and are read only to secure these objects. Alle users can make events that should point to a certain Agenda object.

In events I have a column called agenda which is the pointer to Agenda.

If I try this:

```
var vetEvent = new Parse.Object("Events");
    vetEvent.set('user', Parse.User.current());
    vetEvent.set('type', 'unsubscribe');
    vetEvent.set('agenda', agenda);
    vetEvent.save().then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    },function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
```

The result is:

```
[{"error":{"code":119,"error":"This user is not allowed to perform the update operation on Agenda. You can change this setting in the Data Browser."}}]
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Try using cloudcode in your beforesave event with 'UseMasterKey' that should by pass all security restrictions.

Comment: yeah of course it does, but there should be a better way don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your *Events* class level permissions are not set properly. Add the user column pointer in the class level permissions and make sure it has create/update/delete permissions set.

Comment: I can add an Event as a user without the Agenda object but when I add it I get the error above.

Comment: Yes I can see that. You need to make sure two things are correct. Firstly your agenda field must be a pointer type, so the agenda variable in your code above must be a pointer. Secondly, your class level permissions must have pointer permission set to the user column.